# The method ' [ ] ' was called on null

Tags: flutter, dart

StreamBuilder(

```
                    stream: firestore
                        .collection('users')
                        .document(user.uid)
                        .collection("notes")
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      QuerySnapshot snap = snapshot?.data;
                      List<DocumentSnapshot> notes = snap?.documents;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: notes?.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          DocumentSnapshot doc = notes[index];
                          Map body = doc.data;
                          return Dismissible(
                            key: ObjectKey("${notes[index]}"),
                            background: stackBehindDismiss(),
                            direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                            onDismissed: (v) {
                              deleteNote(doc.documentID);
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (_) => DisplayScreen(
                                        title: body,
                                        docId: doc,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },

                                child: _buildNotes(
                                    context,
                                    "${body["title"]}",
                                    "${body["content"]}"),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      );
                    }),
```

This is the error i get

"The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building:
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling:

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)

#1      _HomeScreenState.build..
(package:firebase_note_app/screens/homescreen.dart:75:59)

#2      SliverChildBuilderDelegate.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:448:22)

#3      SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement._build. (package:flutter/src/widgets
/sliver.dart:1136:67)

#4      _HashMap.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/collection_patch.dart:140:29)
...

"

The StackTrace Points to  "DocumentSnapshot doc = notes[index];"

Comment: what is the 75 line of `homescreen.dart`? the return of your stream is probably null

Comment: "DocumentSnapshot doc = notes[index];"    That is what is in the line 75

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`notes` is `null`. You need to add a check for whether the snapshot has data and display something while it doesn't.

```dart
builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if(snapshot.hasData) {//Check if there is data
                      QuerySnapshot snap = snapshot?.data;
                      List<DocumentSnapshot> notes = snap?.documents;
                      return ListView.builder(
                        physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        itemCount: notes?.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          DocumentSnapshot doc = notes[index];
                          Map body = doc.data;
                          return Dismissible(
                            key: ObjectKey("${notes[index]}"),
                            background: stackBehindDismiss(),
                            direction: DismissDirection.endToStart,
                            onDismissed: (v) {
                              deleteNote(doc.documentID);
                            },
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                              child: InkWell(
                                onTap: () {
                                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (_) => DisplayScreen(
                                        title: body,
                                        docId: doc,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                                },
                       ...
                    }
                    else {//If there isn't data
                      //Return what you want to show before the stream emits its first event
                      return CircularProgressIndicator();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

it seem like typos, you can use ctrl+f to search that key  []

Comment: Didn't find anything

Comment: This is absolutely not a typo